# EXCEL DSUM Double Counting

Tags: excel

As i am new.. i am not able to upload a screenshot of the spreadsheet, so this makes life difficult. I can email a screenshot to anyone that maybe able to help!

I have had a look at previous posts/questions and have not found anyting similair,I hope someone can help!!

I have created a DSUM formula for a cost spreadsheet on a project for two argumets, Phase and work code. the entire spreadsheet seems to work no problems, with the exception of a single £13 value that seems to be double counted. After a bit of chasing i have identified the following

My spreadsheet includes two calculations with criteria:
Formula 1 (Management) - Phase - Work Code
Formula 2 (Design) - Phase - Work Code

1. Column for Management Criteria includes a "DX2" workcode (this is the £13 that appears to be double counted), firstly in the correct formula for management  and again in the next row over for Design
2. If i remove/0 all bar the DX value in Design work code, this still includes the DX2 cost
3. the formatting of DX/DX1/DX2 is identical

Formula is:
=DSUM(BIC_Data,"Expense Cost (1)",G283:H314)

Where:
BIC_Data is a seperate TAB with expense Cost (1) being the data i need to review, the criteria is G283:H314, with the top row including the column headers for Phase and work code

Probably not describing this that well, but any help or advice appreciated

Comment: At least provide the Formulas you are using...

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like your `DX` criterion is picking up anything that **begins** with `DX` including `DX2` and `DX1` etc. so `DX2` gets counted twice, once under `DX` criterion and once for `DX2`.

Make sure you enter the criteria correctly:

Don't enter as `="DX"` (so that `DX` displays)

enter exactly like this

`="=DX"`

[yes, with two = ]

that will display as `=DX`

Comment: +1: an equal sign could be inserted before all criteria by pressing Alt+F11 and entering in the immediate window: `[G284:H314]=["=""="&G284:H314&""""]`